# Solr index-time tokenizer / filter not working as expected?

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm working with a solr instance set up earlier at my company, and it seems to not be set up correctly. I'm able to search for something like `q=*Paper*` to get results but not for `paper`.

It seems like maybe the index-time tokenizer / filter isn't working as I'd expected.

The `schema.xml` is set up to tokenize and then index & query without case sensitivity on this description field for example :

```
<field name="S_DSC" type="string_search" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false"/>
...etc... 

<fieldType name="string_search" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
        <!--Split at whitespaces and at punctuations. Strip other special characters.-->
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <!--Plural words handling. 'dogs'='dog'. Stemming not recommended. dry 'erase' board is not the same as dry board 'eraser'-->
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And the `solrconfig.xml` has the default `qf` set to:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck">false</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">3</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">1</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="defType">synonym_edismax</str>
      <str name="synonyms">false</str>
      <str name="qf">C_PN^20.0 PN^15.0 C_S_DSC^10.0 S_DSC^10.0 M_PN^5.0 DIM_NM^2.0 BRD^2.0 combined_search^1</str>
  <str name="a">{!type=synonym_edismax qf=$qf v=$q}</str>
  </lst>
```

When I query for `q=*` I get results
`select?q=*&rows=10&start=0&wt=json`

```
    "docs": [
        {
            "S_DSC": "Foo 8.5\" x 11\" Copy Paper, 20 lbs, 92 Brightness, 5000/Carton (123456)"
            ...etc...
        },
```

But if I try to search on a term in the description (S_DSC), I don't get results unless it's case sensitive AND I put asterisks around it.

I get results for `q=*Paper*`

```
"parsedquery": "(+DisjunctionMaxQuery((combined_search:*paper* | PN:*Paper*^15.0 | S_DSC:*paper*^10.0 | C_PN:*Paper*^20.0 | BRD:*Paper*^2.0 | M_PN:*Paper*^5.0 | DIM_NM:*Paper*^2.0 | C_S_DSC:*paper*^10.0)))/no_coord",
```

No results for `q=paper`

```
"parsedquery": "(+DisjunctionMaxQuery((combined_search:paper | PN:paper^15.0 | S_DSC:paper^10.0 | C_PN:paper^20.0 | BRD:paper^2.0 | M_PN:paper^5.0 | DIM_NM:paper^2.0 | C_S_DSC:paper^10.0)))/no_coord",
```

No results for `q=Paper`

```
"parsedquery": "(+DisjunctionMaxQuery((combined_search:paper | PN:Paper^15.0 | S_DSC:paper^10.0 | C_PN:Paper^20.0 | BRD:Paper^2.0 | M_PN:Paper^5.0 | DIM_NM:Paper^2.0 | C_S_DSC:paper^10.0)))/no_coord",
```

Shouldn't it be tokenizing the S_DSC above then lowercasing the tokens? (So that `paper` is among them?)
What am I missing here? Appreciate any insight :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `S_DSC` field is not indexed:

```
<field name="S_DSC" type="string_search" --> indexed="false"  <--
```

An unindexed field will never generate a hit. My guess is that your hit is coming from one of the other, unprocessed fields which are indexed, and that's why you're getting the behaviour you're seeing.

When you append `debug=all` to your query, each found document will shown the term frequency matched (i.e. what makes up the score) for each field, allowing you to see which fields generated hits.

Comment: Oh, good catch. I completely overlooked that. Was obsessing over the "stored" field I guess. Appreciate it!